# VCVARSALL.BAT for Visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

What is the location of `vcvarsall.bat` file for Visual Studio 2019 (Preview and future release as well)?

Seems it is different from VS 2017 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat"

Answer (score 40):

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat"

Comment: or "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" if you've got that version.

Comment: or "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" if you've got that version.

Comment: I only have microsoftvisualstudio/installer and microsoftvisualstudio/shared

Answer (score 19):

As it turned out the path is very similar, just without "Community" part:

For VS2019:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat
```

For VS2022 since the toolchain now is 64-bit:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat
```

Comment: I had to add an argument on my side: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64`

Answer (score 18):

If after installing the "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019" and doing all that was recommended in the other answers, you still can't find the the file in the location mentioned (no `Build` folder inside `Auxiliary`) make sure you

Install "**Desktop Development With C++ Workload**"

because vcvarsall.bat is part of C++ workload.

(In VS, go Tools menu -> Get Tools and Features -> Install the Desktop Development With C++ workload)

Comment: To be precise, **the “_C++ CMake tools for Windows_” individual component** included in the “_Desktop development with C++_” workload has `vcvarsall.bat`.

Comment: @КонстантинВан that is not correct - removing "C++ CMake tools for Windows" does not delete that file. Most probably, it's one of CMake's dependencies that has that file. In my case, its seems to be "MSVC v143 - VS 2022 C++ x64/x86 build tools (Latest)". (Interestingly, I had "V14.34-17.4" already installed, but no `vcvarsall.bat` - for some reason, I needed "Latest".)

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019" which can be found [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/).

See the [explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019):

> You can build C and C++ applications on the command line by using tools that are included in Visual Studio. The Microsoft C++ (MSVC) compiler toolset is also downloadable as a standalone package from the Visual Studio downloads page. It's part of the [**Build Tools for Visual Studio package**](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/). You can choose to download only the tools you need for C++ development.

Comment: After installing it I still only have `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS` dir, no `Build` dir and no `vcvarsall.bat`

Comment: After installing the Build Tools, I found the bat files here:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build`

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't installed the "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019", you can do so from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.

Once this is done, the correct path for running vcvarsall.bat is;

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat"

Comment: I only have a `VS` directory inside `Auxiliary`! Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it in the pre-build event, you can execute the vcvars32.bat to set the environment variable VCINSTALLDIR and get rid of the Visual Studio version:

call "$(DevEnvDir)....\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars32.bat"

Then

"%VCINSTALLDIR%\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat"

Note:

-In my tests, the variable VCINSTALLDIR has value only after executing the vcvars32.bat

-As Wei Yang said you need to install "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019", it can be installed using Visual Studio Installer.

Answer (score 0):

I felt free to add a possible solution.

1.) Open the Developer Command Prompt for your wanted         VS if you have more than one installed. BTW this lets you work with TFS tool tf if you need it.

2.) Add in your make script the following code at the concerning location:

```
    for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir /s /b %VSINSTALLDIR%\vcvarsall.bat"') do @set myVCVARSALL=%%d
    if not defined myVCVARSALL exit 1
    call %myVCVARSALL%
```

Hope that helps to find this file for the wanted VS version. It results in different files for different installations.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to install and build some older build tools for windows. So, I had to set the location.
The location is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build`
[image: vcvarsall.bat location]

Comment: IT asks for parameters, for example: vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64
    vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64 10.0.10240.0
    vcvarsall.bat x86_arm uwp 10.0.10240.0
    vcvarsall.bat x86_arm onecore 10.0.10240.0 -vcvars_ver=14.0
    vcvarsall.bat x64 8.1
    vcvarsall.bat x64 store 8.1

But how do I know which ones?

Answer (score 0):

For VS 2019 Professional, it is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat"

Answer (score -8):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat this is the location.

Comment: This is identical to an answer posted 9 months before yours