# Error: vscall.bat is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, terminal

When I try to call vscall.bat or vcvarsall.bat in my x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019, I get the error showed in the title. I tried following this tutorial: [How to tell CMake where to find the compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66861346/how-to-tell-cmake-where-to-find-the-compiler#comment118221628_66861399)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: The script is named as `vcvarsall.bat`. Please, post the exact error message when you use this script.

Comment: This is the exact error message: 'vcvarsall.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to call vscall.bat or vcvarsall.bat **in my x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019**

Since you are already in the x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019 you do not need to call `vcvarsall.bat`. It was already done when you opened that command prompt.