# Why is VS14 getting invoked when I list vs2019_win-64 as a build: requirement?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2019, conda-build

I have the following in my `meta.yaml` file:

```yaml
requirements:
  build:
    - vs2019_win-64  # Uncomment for Windows build only.
{snip}
```

But, when I peruse my (failed) build results I see that VS14 was being invoked:

```
dbanas@Dell-XPS-15 MINGW64 ~/prj/PyBERT (master)
$ tail -n 15 ~/miniconda3/conda-bld/enable_1678736743281/work/build_env_setup.bat | head -n 10
set DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
set MSSdk=1
set PY_VCRUNTIME_REDIST=%LIBRARY_BIN%\vcruntime140.dll
set "VS_VERSION=14.0"
set "VS_MAJOR=14"
set "VS_YEAR=2015"
set "CMAKE_GENERATOR=Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"
set "MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL=/AI;/AL;/OUT;/out"
set "MSYS2_ENV_CONV_EXCL=CL"
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
```

This is, of course, problematic, since the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat` doesn't exist.
(In fact, the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\` doesn't exist.)

**Do I need to add something other than the `vs2019_win-64` `build:` requirement, in order to "steer" the `conda-build` process towards my *Visual Studio 2019* installation?**

**Which of the following batch files replaces `vcvarsall.bat`?**

```
dbanas@Dell-XPS-15 MINGW64 ~/prj/PyBERT (master)
$ find /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio/ -name '*.bat'
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/Common7/Tools/LaunchDevCmd.bat
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/Common7/Tools/vsdevcmd/core/dotnet.bat
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/Common7/Tools/vsdevcmd/core/msbuild.bat
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/Common7/Tools/vsdevcmd/core/parse_cmd.bat
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/Common7/Tools/vsdevcmd/core/vsdevcmd_end.bat
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/Common7/Tools/vsdevcmd/core/vsdevcmd_start.bat
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/Common7/Tools/vsdevcmd/core/winsdk.bat
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/Common7/Tools/vsdevcmd/ext/netfxsdk.bat
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/Common7/Tools/vsdevcmd/ext/roslyn.bat
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/Common7/Tools/VsDevCmd.bat
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/Common7/Tools/VsMSBuildCmd.bat
```

Comment: Did you open a command prompt labeled "for VS 2015"?  To support side-by-side installs each of the "DOS Box" command prompt icons will point to a different set of environment variables.  The VS 2015 box to 2015, the 2019 box to 2019.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to an incomplete *Visual Studio* installation.
Contrary to many tips I found, just installing the *Build Tools for C/C++* package is not enough to support `conda build`.
You also need to install the *Desktop Development with C++ Workload* package, as per [this helpful gem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67517375/1549736).

After modifying my *Visual Studio* installation to include that package, I have the `vcvarsall.bat` file back again:

```
dbanas@Dell-XPS-15 MINGW64 ~/prj/PyBERT (master)
$ find /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio/ -name 'vcvarsall.bat'
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvarsall.bat
```

And my `conda build` now succeeds! :)