# GraalVm: Failed to find 'vcvarsall.bat' in a Visual Studio installation

Tags: java, graalvm

I'm using GraalVM and trying to make exe file from jar file, but it said:

> Error: Failed to find 'vcvarsall.bat' in a Visual Studio installation.
> Please make sure that Visual Studio 2022 version 17.1.0 or later is installed on your system. You can download it at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/. If this error persists, please try and run GraalVM Native Image in an x64 Native Tools Command Prompt or file a ticket.

In GraalVM docs, it said that I have to install MSVC, Windows 10 SDK, CMake, Testing tool,... I installed all of them except my SDK is Windows 11 SDK but I think it should have been compatible with Windows 10 SDK.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thank you.

[My Visual Studio Installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0fUl.png)

Comment: Can you check if the file exists in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat ?

Comment: @Michael yeah I have vcvarsall.bat, but I installed VS 2022 in D drive, so my path is D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also installed **D** and encountered the error: `Unable to find vcvarsall.bat`. After some research, I found this article that suggested the issue might be related to environment variables: How I Solved Error: Unable to Find `vcvarsall.bat`.

To resolve this, I modified the `native-image.cmd` file by adding the following lines:

**cmd:**

```
@echo off
call "D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" > null
```

This modification successfully fixed the issue for me. I hope this solution helps anyone else facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error is likely caused by toolchain autodetection code. So one idea is to make autodetection unnecessary:

Run Command Prompt. From inside it, run `vcvarsall.bat` first, then `native-image`. If it still fails, try adding `-H:-CheckToolchain` parameter

Comment: Sadly both of them are not work for me

Answer (score 0):

For those who do not have `vcvarsall.bat` (normally found in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build`), [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55097222/vcvarsall-bat-for-visual-studio-2019) learned me that it can be installed by installing the "Desktop development with C++" package found under "Workloads" in the Visual Studio installer.

Answer (score 0):

The official code package is a fixed path, which has been changed, but without the latest release, graalvm-jdk-21.0.2+13.1 is now problematic.

https://github.com/oracle/graal/commit/bc2fbe9459f3a9150fe85e314c8a71afec628002#diff-967ec4e4a1a8ba71149a7f0a19524b48ad2e9f9b1a8ed53f0699f28859ab9c02

Try placing the installation path in the following location:
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio`